# Disable WEBVIEW to go back, but enable AlertDialoge to exit the app on back press

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a situation in which I want to disable my WEBVIEW to go back on the back key pressed, but at the main screen, I want my app to ask for an AlertDialog to ask me that, do I need to exit the app? I have tried this::

```
  webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch(keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                            //webView.goBack();//

                            return true;
                        } else {

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            finishAffinity(); // Close all activites
                                            System.exit(0);
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                            alert.show();
                        }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the `onBackPressed` at the activity level?

This is usually an easier way to change the back button behaviour

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()

e.g.

```java
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    ...
    }
```

Update:

Thinking about it more this is probably a focus issue, the webview might not always being the focus of the key events.

It would be best to handle the exit App Dialog at the Activity level with `onBackPressed` and not going back on the web pages in the webview.

I'm not sure that using and `onKeyListener` is most reliable as it is meant for hardware keyboards. Another method of preventing a webview going back is to clear the history once the webview has finished loading so there is nothing for it to go back to. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#clearHistory()